# Big text on left and block of text on right

Tags: pdftex

I was beating my head up with latex for this but couldn't come up with a properly formatted output.

So basically, what I want is a large font text on the left (Company name) and 2-3 lines of comparitively small text on the right in line with the large text. ( Address of the company)

So basically, I want something like

ABC COMPANY `<Empty Space>`Address

Where ABC Company is large font and Address in a block of 3 lines in parallel to the big text. I hope it makes it clear.

Can anyone help? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use two `minipage` environments, separated/flushed by `\hfill`. The alignment inside the minipages can be switched to top-aligned by replacing the `[b]` with a `[t]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\textwidth}
\raggedright
\Large Company Name
\end{minipage}
%
\hfill
%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\textwidth}
\raggedleft
99 MyStreet\\
ZIP Code etc.\\
The City of New Orleans
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
\noindent
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```